# change cssmin and uglify output directories using usemin and grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm

When using `usemin`, the output directory for `cssmin` and `uglifyjs` is by default set to `dist/assets/`.

I want to offer a different directory to place my new files in, ie: `assets/`.

I can't seem to figure out, how to change these settings in my gruntfile using `usemin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the dest in options like so:

```
    useminPrepare: {
        html: 'app/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: './'
        }
    },
```